# How to set destructuring values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this:

```
  const { 
    user,
    id,
    name,
    desc,
    photos,
    video,
    price,
  } = route.params;

  <ProductFooter 
    selectedOptions={selectedOptions}
    {...route.params}
  />
```

Now I want to get the user in a variable and the other props in another variable

```
const ProductFooter = ({...props}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const user = the user props,
  const product = the other props
```

How can I set now the values ?

Comment: Is there something that [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) does not answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) operator. That helps in object/array destructuring.

```js
const obj ={ 
a : 1, b: 2, c : 3, user : 'joe' };

const { user, ...rest } = obj;
console.log(user);
console.log(rest);
```

Comment: but how I do it with ...props <- , ? this not working:   const data = {
    user,
    ...rest
  } = ...props

Comment: `const data` is not required. `const { user, ...rest } = props`  should do it.

Comment: Also, no need to destructure at top. `const ProductFooter = ({...props})`. Just do `const ProductFooter = (props)`

Comment: Ok but I need to acceess the user, like ProductFooter.user, but thats not working   const footerProps = (props);
  const { user, ...rest } = footerProps;

Comment: `const ProductFooter = (props) {` was for the function expression.Also footerProps is not defined yet. Seems like you need to first start with basics of javascript and react. Please do not jump into learning fancy operators now

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure your props object like this, and just assign the `...rest` :

```
const ProductFooter = ({ user, ...rest }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const product = rest;
```

Don't forget you are also passing `selectedOptions` which will be assigned with `...rest` unless you separate it out like with `user`.